# View archive menu without creating archive

Tags: xcode

In xcode I want to access the archive menu, to release a previous archive to the app store. The only way I know to get there is through the menu bar -> Product -> Archive.

The problem is that this creates a new archive automatically.

How can I reach this menu without creating a new archive?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the Window menu choose the Organizer option and then select the Archives tab on the window that appears.